# Linear layout divide not equally width

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I know how to divide a layout into 3 or 4 equal parts, but how do I divide a linear layout (horizontal) into 4 parts in this way?

[image]
As you can see, part number "1" is 3 times parts "3" and "4".
Instead, part number "2" is 2 times parts "3" and "4".

I've tried like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edColore"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="ARANCIONE" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edGiorno"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edOra"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edPosizione"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But don't work as I want:
[image]

Comment: In the main linear layout try giving weightsum = 7 and change 1st Linear to weight 3

Comment: All the answers you received until now are good. I just wanted to add a suggestion: just use a ConstraintLayout. It will be easier and cleaner to get what you are trying to achieve with LinearLayout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [**`android:weightSum`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout#attr_android:weightSum)

> Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by
>   adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for
>   instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by
>   giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.

Your **XML** will

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="8" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edColore"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="ARANCIONE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edGiorno"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edOra"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edPosizione"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edColore"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="ARANCIONE" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edGiorno"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edOra"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edPosizione"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this latest code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/edColore"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:text="ARANCIONE" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/edGiorno"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/edOra"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/edPosizione"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```